# No description about making CRUD using the sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, sails.js

I am learning docker and also sails from `https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/nodejs/porting/1_node_application.md` tutorial

And I have one problem or I think it's not too enough.
After `sails generate API message`, I can see only the message model and controller generated.
And there is no description about how to create controller and model for CRUD(only test case)

Please help me if you have experience with Sails.js
Thank you

Comment: Should I code by own? Is there any way to generate code?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.
I should select 2 when I create `sails new messageApp` and make changes `rest:true` om the `config/blueprint.js`

Comment: Very nice, I'm not sure why this isn't in their docs but as a previous Rails dev, this tripped me up on why it wasn't working. For other clarifcation, `rest:true` in `config/blueprint.js` opens things up when you run `sails lift`, it's not a config for `sails generate`. So once you set this, you'll get those routes automatically.